# Objective-C method returns NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary. Why?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, objective-c-blocks

I am using the included method to return a pointer to a NSMutableDictionary, that is contained in an NSArray.  However, the NSMutableArray (theOne) is being created as a non-mutuable NSDictionary.  This is a problem because I want to modify the dictionary after retrieving it with this method.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary*)getMatFromBoutKey:(NSString*) boutKey
{   
    /*
     * Returns the mat object with the provided boutKey.
     * Returns nil if no mat has that boutKey.
     */

    NSUInteger idx = [[event objectForKey:@"mats"] indexOfObjectPassingTest:
                      ^ BOOL (NSMutableDictionary* obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                      {
                          return [[obj objectForKey:@"boutKey"] isEqualToString:boutKey];
                      }];

    if (idx == NSNotFound)
        return nil;
    else {
        NSMutableDictionary* theOne = [[event objectForKey:@"mats"] objectAtIndex: idx];
        return theOne;
    }
}
```

Here's an image of the debugger stopped on a breakpoint right after the theOne is first referenced.

[image: Image of the debugger showing that theOne is not mutable]

Why isn't theOne mutable?  How can I return a pointer to the NSMutableDictionary so that I can modify it after I get the value returned to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Is [event objectForKey:@"mats"] an array of mutable dictionary?

Comment: What is event?  Where is that coming from?

Comment: Do not prefix methods with `get`.  That should just be `matFromBoutKey:`.

Comment: Yes, [event objectForKey:@"mats"] is an array of mutable dictionaries.  I create event in another class.  Event is a property of both that class, and the class that holds the code from above.   Thanks @bbum, I'll make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have a dictionary of arrays. Then that array contains a bunch of regular dictionaries. So when you pull it out of the array it is still a regular dictionary regardless of what you assign it to.

For instance, take the following code for example

```
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *mutDict = dict;
```

mutDict will contain a regular dictionary because it has not properly been casted to a mutable dictionary.

either make sure when you create the array that is at [event objectForKey:@"mats"] that you put NSMutable dictionaries inside of it OR

use

```
NSMutableDictionary* theOne = [[[event objectForKey:@"mats"] objectAtIndex: idx] mutableCopy];
```

When taking the data out

Comment: Yes, event is a NSMutableDictionary, with an NSArray called mats, mats holds NSMutableDictionaries.   I do put NSMutableDictionaries into the array.  If I use mutableCopy when I take the dictionaries out, that just gives me a copy, not a pointer to the real object, right?  I'm taking a deeper look at how I put the dictionaries in, to be sure they are going in the way I think.

Comment: I found the problem.   Had a loop that reassigned to the mats to NSDictionaries.  It's fixed. now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general, I think it's better practice to work with immutable objects when mutability isn't strictly necessary. Mutable objects use more memory, and of course have the potential of being accidentally changed. Maybe in the block are being changed to the enumerator(I'm not sure, but it is possible. For faster indexing). If you want to change a mutable object is via **`mutableCopy`**. or using a other method.

Comment: I actually believe it is a common misconception that Mutable Objects require more memory. From my understanding a NSMutableDictionary is just a subclass of NSDictionary with more connivence methods thrown on it.  The same could probably be accomplished with a category on NSDictionary.

Comment: Mutable objects require more memory, are slower, and -- the real reason -- break encapsulation, leading to fragility.  Note that for collections with only a handful of objects, the performance differences will be negligible.  The fragility, however, is a significant issue.

Comment: I understand the fragility issue however, could you please post a source to where you are getting the information that they are slower and require more memory? I am almost certain I have seen a WWDC video where an Apple Engineer said they were just a simple subclass with connivence methods.

Comment: In my case, I have am using mutable dictionaries because I need to their contents on a regular basis.  I only change them from one place.   I'm not sure what I can do to protect them.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a mutable dictionary then. MutableDictionaries are used if you are constantly adding, removing, and changing objects within the dictionary. You can access the content of a regular NSDictionary as much as you want. You just can't add, remove and change key-value pairs once the dictionary has been made.

Answer (score 0):

Is it inserted as mutable elsewhere in the code? If so it should return as mutable, if not you can send it the `mutableCopy` message to get a mutable copy (that has a reference count of 1, so be sure to release it when necessary).